# Creating a New SKU Via Stripe API from a Script in Gatsby React

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, gatsby

I want to create a new SKU via the stripe API. But, it looks like the Stripe API doesn't support Gatsby: https://stripe.com/docs/api/skus/create?lang=node - the "closest" thing would be Node.js --- which isn't even close to Gatsby.

I've tried coping and pasting the Node.js version of the code but I believe it breaks the Gatsby compilation procedure because it's using Node.js syntax - which isn't allowed in my React/Gatsby syntax.

```
        var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_secret_key");

        stripe.skus.create({
          product: '200',
          attributes: {size: 'Medium', gender: 'Unisex'},
          price: 1500,
          currency: 'usd',
          inventory: {type: 'finite', quantity: 500}
        }, function(err, sku) {
          // asynchronously called
        });
```

This doesn't compile at all.

Is creating SKU's in Stripe just 100% incompatible with Gatsby? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Gatsby is very much a Node.js app! You can put this code in `gatsby-node.js` in the root folder (if there's none, you can create one with that name.) Depending what you want to do once you get the SKU, you can put it in one of gatsby node API hooks.

Comment: You are so good at Gatsby! I appreciate you sharing your knowledge. I will have to look deeper into this because I had no idea it has a node.js component. Wow!